# Performance object properties vs scope variables

Tags: c++

This is a probably a beginner question.

A.h

```
class A
{
private:

    short* arrObject;

public:
    A();
    ~A();

    void func0();
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "Timer.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

A::A()
{
    arrObject = new short[4];
}


A::~A()
{
}


void A::func0() {
    Timer timer; // this class measures time in seconds

    short* arrScope = new short[4];

    timer.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        arrScope[3] = 987;
    }
    cout << "Writing in scope array " << timer.end() << endl;

    timer.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        arrObject[3] = 987;
    }
    cout << "Writing in object array " << timer.end() << endl;

    cout << endl;
}
```

Calling `func0` on an instance of `A` produces output:

```
Writing in scope array 0
Writing in object array 0.000771421
```

This implies that using object properties is slower than using scope variables. Why is that so?

I am using Visual Studio 2013, so it's Microsoft C/C++ Compiler.
The optimization is selected in VS as "Maximize Speed /O2"

EDIT:

In addition, if I change A.h into:

```
class A
{
private:

    short arrObject[4];

public:
    A();
    ~A();

    void func0();
};
```

and lose the initialization from the construction in A.cpp, the difference disappears and the output is:

```
Writing to scope array 0
Writing to object array 3.31082-007
```

Comment: Compiler, optimization level?

Comment: I do not think you are measuring what you think you are measuring.  Since this code is a non-op most likely the compiler is optimizing away the loops.

Comment: Always check disassembly if you are optimizing something.

Comment: The biggest performance drain is usually `new`/`malloc`. It takes an eternity compared to an object on the stack.

Comment: I guess you're migrating from another language. What you call "object properties" are called _member variables_ in C++. There's no equivalent term for "scope variable" that I know of. As mentioned, the optimiser probably sees that your loops are utterly pointless and eliminates them. Also, I'll invoke the oft-quoted Knuth: "Premature optimisation [by the programmer] is the root of all evil." Don't obsess over minuscule speed-ups unless you've proven both existence of inefficiency and a need to go faster. But... in theory, mvars might incur slight cost for the `this` offset, if it's not cached.

Comment: Actually, is's not the code that is migrating but me. This question was a first suspicious thing in a larger problem that is not pure C/C++, but involves OpenCV: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749923/opencv-fast-detector

Answer (score 1):

Ok so, yes, it is the optimization thing.

If I disable all optimizations, both timers show exact times.
Also, if I keep the optimization and mess up the code a little instead:

```
void A::func0() {
    Timer timer;

    short* arrScope = new short[4];

    timer.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        arrScope[i % 4] = i;
    }
    cout << "Writing in scope array " << timer.end() << endl;

    timer.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        arrObject[i%4] = i;
    }
    cout << "Writing in object array " << timer.end() << endl;



    cout << endl;
}
```

The timers also show same times.

```
Run #1: 0.00263972 / 0.00267415
Run #2: 0.00069362 / 0.00099159
Run #3: 0.00251192 / 0.00250728
```

Comment: What are those times?